# andThen in List scala

Tags: scala

Has anyone got an example of how to use andThen with Lists? I notice that andThen is defined for List but the documentations hasn't got an example to show how to use it.

My understanding is that f andThen g means that execute function f and then execute function g. The input of function g is output of function f. Is this correct?

**Question 1 - I have written the following code but I do not see why I should use andThen because I can achieve the same result with map.**

```
scala> val l = List(1,2,3,4,5)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

//simple function that increments value of element of list
scala> def f(l:List[Int]):List[Int] = {l.map(x=>x-1)}
f: (l: List[Int])List[Int]

//function which decrements value of elements of list
scala> def g(l:List[Int]):List[Int] = {l.map(x=>x+1)}
g: (l: List[Int])List[Int]

scala> val p = f _ andThen g _
p: List[Int] => List[Int] = <function1>

//printing original list
scala> l
res75: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

//p works as expected.
scala> p(l)
res74: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

//but I can achieve the same with two maps. What is the point of andThen?
scala> l.map(x=>x+1).map(x=>x-1)
res76: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Could someone share practical examples where andThen is more useful than methods like filter, map etc. One use I could see above is that with andThen, I could create a new function,p, which is a combination of other functions. But this use brings out usefulness of andThen, not List and andThen

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`andThen` is inherited from `PartialFunction` a few parents up the inheritance tree for `List`. You use `List` as a `PartialFunction` when you access its elements by index. That is, you can think of a `List` as a function from an index (from zero) to the element that occupies that index within the list itself.

If we have a list:

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

We can call `list` like a function (because it is one):

```
scala> list(0)
res5: Int = 1
```

`andThen` allows us to compose one `PartialFunction` with another. For example, perhaps I want to create a `List` where I can access its elements by index, and then multiply the element by `2`.

```
val list2 = list.andThen(_ * 2)

scala> list2(0)
res7: Int = 2

scala> list2(1)
res8: Int = 4
```

This is essentially the same as using `map` on the list, except the computation is lazy. Of course, you could accomplish the same thing with a `view`, but there might be some generic case where you'd want to treat the `List` as just a `PartialFunction`, instead (I can't think of any off the top of my head).

---

In your code, you aren't actually using `andThen` on the `List` itself. Rather, you're using it for functions that you're passing to `map`, etc. There is no difference in the results between mapping a `List` twice over `f` and `g` and mapping once over `f andThen g`. However, using the composition is preferred when mapping multiple times becomes expensive. In the case of `List`s, traversing multiple times can become a tad computationally expensive when the list is large.

Answer (score 2):

With the solution `l.map(x=>x+1).map(x=>x-1)` you are traversing the list twice.
When composing 2 functions using the `andThen` combinator and then applying it to the list, you only traverse the list once.

```
val h = ((x:Int) => x+1).andThen((x:Int) => x-1)
l.map(h) //traverses it only once
```